# Rewrite rule for a directory to redirect its parent directory in Apace2.conf file

Tags: php, apache, apache2

I want a rewrite rule in `Apace2.conf` file so that it will redirect the user when he enters a particular directory. 
e.g.,
`www.mywebsite.com/folder` then it will redirect to `www.mywebsite.com`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

Comment: Please can you provide code for redirect rule in Apace2.conf

Comment: you can use RedirectMatch. http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/weblinux2/apache/ch08_01.htm

Comment: is there any way to do it in Apace2.conf file.